# How to save data from multiple NSTextFields and NSComboBoxes within an NSArray

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, plist

As the title states I am trying to pull data from two NSComboBoxes and two NSTextFields. I am then adding the data to a basic NSArray to save it to a plist. My current problem is that I have been able to get data from the first but not the second NSTextField. I have tried using `objectValue` and `stringValue`. Both return only data from the first box.

```
NSString *path =@"/myplist.plist";
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[dropBuild objectValueOfSelectedItem], [dropDept objectValueOfSelectedItem], [roomNumber objectValue], [cDesc objectValue], nil];
NSDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:array, @"ArrayKey", @"SomeString", @"StringKey", nil];

[plist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

I understand that this is not the best of code, but I am new to the language. I found this array online and ran with it.

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Removing the last NStextField (cDesc) and adding a new textfield  allowed the array to function properly. I had added new fields previously, but i never removed the faulty field. All I can say is you make stupid mistakes when you are learning a new language.

Thank you to anyone who reads this in the future. I know will be back to this site for advice in the future.